# CoreData: does findAllWithPredicate work properly?

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using Magical Record library. Its cool but I have some trouble.
My second method return incorrect data. First and second methods must return the same quantity of quotes. Does findAllWithPredicate work properly?

**UNLOCK AND FETCH QUOTES**

```
-(NSArray*) unlockAndFetchQuotes
{
 CoreDataManager *instance = [CoreDataManager instance];
 [instance unlockUnitNumber:1];
 return [instance fetchQuotes];
}
```

**UNLOCK UNIT NUMBER**

```
-(void) unlockUnitNumber:(int) number
{
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identificator=%d", number];
 NSArray *array =[CDInApp findAllWithPredicate:predicate];
 if (array.count>0)
 {
    CDInApp *inApp = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    inApp.isLockedValue = NO;
    [[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveNestedContexts];
 }
}
```

**FETCH QUOTES**

```
-(NSArray*) fetchQuotes
{
 int z=0;
 NSArray *arr = [CDQuotes findAll];
 for (CDQuotes * quotes in arr)
 {
    if (!quotes.inApp.isLockedValue)
    {
        z++;
    }
 }
   NSLog(@"_____ unlocked quotes by first method %d", z);


 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"inApp.isLocked != 1"];
 int count = [CDQuotes countOfEntitiesWithPredicate:predicate];
   NSLog(@"_____ unlocked quotes by second method %d", count);

 NSArray *array = [CDQuotes findAllWithPredicate:predicate];
   NSLog(@"total unlocked array %d", array.count);

 return array;
}
```

First and second methods must return the same quantity of quotes. The second method doesn't work properly.

**My output**

```
___ must be unlocked quotes 500
___ unlocked quotes by first method 500
___ unlocked quotes by second method 250
total unlocked array 250
```

[image]

**UPDATE2**

I found a problem. Firstly I do unlockAndFetchQuotes. I trace this function and found something strange. **Saving to coredata goes after fetching quotes.** Now I'm looking for soluions to save instantely.

```
2012-12-21 18:13:32.992 CoreBug[6713:11603] _____ unlocked quotes by first method 8
2012-12-21 18:13:32.994 CoreBug[6713:11603] _____ unlocked quotes by second method 6
2012-12-21 18:13:32.996 CoreBug[6713:11603] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithErrorCallback:](0x7464700) -> Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x7464700): *** DEFAULT ***> on *** MAIN THREAD ***
2012-12-21 18:13:32.997 CoreBug[6713:15603] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithErrorCallback:](0x8148ef0) -> Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x8148ef0): *** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD ***
```

I unlocked my unit and fetched quotes.

Comment: The "identificator" or which entity are you trying to reference in your predicate?

Comment: I have 1000 quotes and 4 inApp unit. One inApp object is responsible for 250 quotes. I can easily lock/unlock my quotes. I don't fully understand your question.

Comment: You have `predicateWithFormat:@"identificator=%d"`. What entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

saveNestedContexts is async method. I need to use another method

```
[localContext MR_saveNestedContextsErrorHandler:nil completion:^{
        [self fetchQuotes];
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `isLockedValue` in your loop, instead of `isLocked`. Presumably, `isLockedValue` does not exist and will always be `nil`, resulting in all items in the loop to be counted.

By contrast, your predicate seems to be working correctly.

Comment: When the CoreData classes are generated `isLockedValue` allows read/write access as a `BOOL` where `isLocked` is an `NSNumber`. Also accessing a property that does not exist likely would have crashed.

Comment: So did you try `ìsLocked` instead and get expected results?

Comment: So you should NSLog your fetch result and see what values you have in your data. Alternatively, use the `sqlite3` command line tool.

Comment: Please see my update2. Saving to coredata goes after fetching quotes. Now I'm looking for soluions to save instantely.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your predicate to be

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"inApp.isLocked = NO"]
```

?

Comment: The result is the same. Please see my update section where I found something strange.